# Contractor not ready to put gravel for concrete walkway

Tags: concrete, gravel, walkway, sidewalk

I really need advice since I’m getting conflicting information.

Can a concrete walkway be made without gravel base or ABC? When I contracted for the work I assumed that there would be gravel since I always used gravel base for concrete patio.

The contractor says it’s not needed and he never does that for any walkway.

The walkway will be laid on clay soil and the contractor doesn’t plan to use any rebar.  It will be used to walk to the backyard so it will be lightly used.

Is gravel a must it can I do without it ?

Comment: Where are you located?

Comment: Charlotte , North Carolina

Answer (score 2):

One of the reasons for gravel is to create a barrier between the soil and the concrete so the water from the concrete doesn't absorb into the soil. You can eliminate the gravel but would need to install plastic sheeting on top of the well compacted clay soil. I'd be requesting steel mesh be used even on a walkway.

Answer (score 1):

Gravel is not needed for under a walkway. Rebar is not used as well for a standard 4inch pour. Wiremesh can be used, but the contractor may be using fiberglass reinforced concrete, ( rough strands of fiberglass are mixed in with the concrete) The fiberglass binds very well and then no wire is needed.

Comment: Thanks so much.